# How to patch array fields in subdocumented schema structure in mongodb,nodejs taking values from user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

Please dont give a solution which doesn't match requirement.
I am writing REST api, GET,POST,PUT,DELETE are working awesome but i am having problem with PATCH, if you can please correct it. I am attaching required code, if you need full code please comment so with your contact details.

Modelfile1: TaskInfo Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var taskInfo = mongoose.Schema({

     isactive:{type:Boolean}, 
     taskobject:{type:String}, 
     taskdetails:{type:String}, 
     iscompleted:{type:Boolean}

    });


    var TaskInfo = mongoose.model('TaskInfo', taskInfo);
    module.exports.TaskInfo = TaskInfo;
    module.exports.TaskInfoSchema = taskInfo;
```

Model file 2 Task Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TaskInfoSchema = require("./taskinfo.js").TaskInfoSchema

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Task schema
var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({

 tasktype  : {type: String},
 createdon : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 //createdby : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'},
 //visitedby : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}],
 taskinfo  : [TaskInfoSchema]  

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

Route file api.js-- You have to correct this file ---

```
var TaskInfo = require('../models/taskinfo.js').TaskInfo;
var Task = require('../models/task.js');
var config = require('../../config');
module.exports = function (app, express) {

    var api = express.Router();

    //GET method is for fetching all the tasks from the database,
    api.get('/taskdb', function (req, res) {

        //console.log("____");

        Task.find({}, function (err, taskdb) {

            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(taskdb);
        });
    });


    //POST method is for saving all the tasks to the database,
    api.post('/tasks', function (req, res) {

        var task = {};
        task.tasktype = req.body.tasktype;

        task.taskinfo = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < req.body.taskInfo.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var taskInfo = new TaskInfo(req.body.taskInfo[i]);
            task.taskinfo.push(taskInfo);
        }

        var taskObj = new Task(task);

        taskObj.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Task has been created'
            })

        });
    });

//middleware 

    api.use('/tasks/:taskId',function(req, res, next){

      Task.findById(req.params.taskId, function(err, task){

        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
               }
        else if(task)
        {
          req.task = task;
          next();
        }
        else
        {
        res.status(404).send ('no task found with such details');
        }
        });
    });


!-- // PLEASE CORRECT THIS PATCH METHOD --! want to partial update array fields

//patch method--- wrong implementation (google how to patch array fields)
api.patch ('/tasks/:taskId',function(req,res){
 // if(req.body._id)
  //  delete req.body._id;

   if(req.body.tasktype)
 {
  req.task.tasktype =  req.body.tasktype; 
 }


  req.task.save(function(err){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
        }
       res.json({message:'Task edited & updated '})

    });
});


// update error put method code isn't working for boolean fields  -- have to input 0 or 1 (then works correct)
//put method
api.put ('/tasks/:taskId',function(req,res){

//var task = {};
        req.task.tasktype = req.body.tasktype;

        req.task.taskinfo = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < req.body.taskInfo.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var taskInfo = new TaskInfo(req.body.taskInfo[i]);
            req.task.taskinfo.push(taskInfo);
        }



        req.task.save(function(err){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
        }
       res.json({message:'User info updated successfully'})

    });      

});

//put ends here

//Task deletion is working fine 

api.delete ('/tasks/:taskId',function(req,res){
       req.task.remove(function(err){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
        }
       res.json({message:'Task has been deleted'})
  });
     });

api.get('/tasks/:taskId',function(req, res){

       res.json(req.task);
    });



    return api
}
```

Json file:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "55f7a31c83dc2aa80b549516",
    "__v": 13,
    "tasktype": "Extreme",
    "taskinfo": [
      {
        "_id": "55f84a6e110db2bc0d5159a2",
        "iscompleted": false,
        "taskdetails": "This is task 1",
        "taskobject": "paid",
        "isactive": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "55f84a6e110db2bc0d5159a3",
        "iscompleted": false,
        "taskdetails": "This is task 2",
        "taskobject": "paid",
        "isactive": false
      },
      {
        "_id": "55f84a6e110db2bc0d5159a4",
        "iscompleted": true,
        "taskdetails": "This is task 3",
        "taskobject": "paid",
        "isactive": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "55f84a6e110db2bc0d5159a5",
        "iscompleted": false,
        "taskdetails": "This is task 4",
        "taskobject": "paid",
        "isactive": false
      }
    ],
    "createdon": "2015-09-15T04:48:28.631Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this working not using your above code, but directly from mongo shell  ?  Its handy to battle these syntax issues from [there](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/) before implementing in code.   I am also using mongoose and my PATCH uses the mongo update as per

```
DB.update(

    myQuery,
    {
        $set: req.body
    }
)
```

see doc at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

You can see it has built in a query to perform the find. Example myQuery :

```
{ id: '4' }
```

In my case I feed in the actual update in my req.body . Example req.body :

```
{ surname: 'Beethoven' }
```

This works.

Comment: Sir in above code where it is mentioned thatwhich element we want to update ? taskInfo is array field(subdocumented) ... Can you write the proper code for patch so that I can verify it by running it on my side. 
Btw I have sorted how to update tasktype field performing edit for same.
Thank You

Comment: please can you write REST api for PATCH like i have done for PUT,GET,POST,& DELETE ??? I am not able to figure out thats why posted here and have refernced docs .